# Enable/Disable Button in angular when I modify form

Tags: angular, typescript

I work on a bug and I want to prevent user to save the data he don't enter any data in the form. The form is created like this:

```
private buildAddressPopupForm() {
this.form = this.fb.group({
  roles: [''],
  addressLine1: [this.data.addressLine1],
  addressLine2: [this.data.addressLine2],
  city: [this.data.city],
  state: [this.data.state],
  postalCode: [this.data.postalCode],
  country: [this.data.country],
  startDate: [],
  endDate: [],
  isNew: [this.data.isNew],
  phone: [this.data.phone],
  fax: [this.data.fax],
  mobile: [this.data.mobile],
  email: [this.data.email],
  website: [this.data.website],
  active: [this.data.active === undefined ? true : this.data.active],
});
```

}

I don't have Apply and Cancel Buttons, they came from another library so I overrode them:

```
createButtons() {
let applyButton = {
  label: "apply",
  id: "apply",
  disabled: true,
  onClick: () => this.onApplyPopup()
}
let cancelButton = {
  label: "cancel",
  id: "cancel",
  disabled: false,
  onClick: () => this.onClosePopup()
}
this.buttons.push(applyButton);
this.buttons.push(cancelButton);
```

}

```
onApplyPopup() {
if (this.form.valid) {
  this.applyPopup.emit(this.form.value);
}
```

}

```
onClosePopup() {
    this.closePopup.next();
  }
```

After I hit Apply an event emitter is send and data is pushed in an array.

Those 2 methods: createButtons() and buildAddressPopupForm()  are called in ngOnInit and the Apply button is by default disabled. I want that my button to be enabled when I change the form but I don't know how because buttons are created one time and ngOnInit is called just when the component is created. I tried with event emitter but I didn't come to a result.Any help will be apreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the `statusChanges` Observable of your `FormGroup`.

First you need to keep track of your button:

```js
createButtons() {
  // create this property in your class
  this.applyButton = {
    label: "apply",
    id: "apply",
    disabled: true,
    onClick: () => this.onApplyPopup()
  }
...
}
```

then in your `ngOnInit` you subscribe to the observable and update the disabled state of your button:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.form.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
    if (status === 'VALID' && this.form.touched) {
      this.applyButton.disabled = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. I tried this way and still can'tdo it. The createButtons() function that creates the button is also called in ngOnInit() and initially the button is disabled. after that I subscribe in ngOnInit as you said, the button will be enabled. so in the end the button will be enabled even if I don't change anything in the form

Comment: you can use this.form.valuechanges.subscribe((res) =>{ console.log(res) });
you can put this at end of ngOnInit() or you can employe ngOnChanges()

Comment: If I put on the end of ngOnInit the button will have the value from the valueChanges.subscribe because the ngOnInit is triggered just one time..And in ngOnChanges I need to work with an @Input() field

Comment: @EugenGîrlescu If this is the case, you can add a condition for touched. I edited my answer to reflect that.
The thing about observables and subscribe is that the function in subscribe will be called every time the `statusChanges` Observable emits a new value. In `ngOnInit` your are only registering it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way!

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message: ''
  });

  this.onChanges();
}

    onChanges(): void {
      this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I don't understand your answer, I am new to Angular. I know what is dirty and touched but I cannot understand how cand I check if a form is touched if she is disabled..

Comment: Please refer the documentation here:
https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#inherited-from-abstractcontroldirective

Comment: How can I touch a form if she is disabled? I don't understand your sugestion and your approach

Comment: form has a property called touched. It returns boolean. Enable buttons only when form is touched.

Comment: I create the form and the buttons in ngOnInit, applyButton is by default disabled. I want an approach to enable that button when I change some value from form but I cannot do this with valuesChanges or statusChanges because I must subscribe to them in ngOnInit and it doesn't change the button status. If I subscribe in ngOncHanges the same, it doesn't work..I cannot call the touched property for form, on the button because I create that button in ngOnInit and the component is created only once

Comment: Please share valueChanges code here.

Comment: It should be like 
ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    message: ''
  });

  this.onChanges();
}

onChanges(): void {
  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  });
}

Comment: It works only if I have Validators.required on fields.. and I don't have because fields are not required.